# Is there a way to "align" text in a LaTeX report table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

I'm using a LaTeX report style to construct a document. Each section has a title that begins with a date, like this:

```
Sun Jan 11 2015 - A Sunny Day
Wed Feb 4 2015 - A Rainy Day
Thu Mar 5 2015 - A Cloudy Day
```

Because the font is proportional, the dashes don't line up. Is there a way to force the dash + the subsequent text to line up without making the text monospaced?

Comment: What does your input mechanism look like? Or what would you like it to be?

Comment: Isn't it better to use the date instead of section number and the section title, i.e. `A sunny day`?

Answer (score 2):

A small proposition, in lack of more features. It will break the appearances of `\section` etc. in the ToC however.

The date itself is used instead of a section number, but this date is not aligned so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{70pt}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \StrBefore{#7}{ - }[\@@firstpart]
  \StrBehind{#7}{ - }[\@@remainder]
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\@@firstpart}%
    \fi
    - \@@remainder
  }
}{}{}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Sun Jan 11 2015 - A Sunny Day}
\section{Wed Feb 4  2015 - A Cloudy Day}
\section{Tue Mar 4  2015 - A Rainy Day}
\end{document}
```

[image]